# Devexpress ASPxGridViewExporter will not export leading zeros

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, export-to-excel, aspxgridview

Is there a property I need to set for it to export this number with leading zeroes to excel? or Perhaps a setting on the grid itself? Something to force it to be treated as a string instead of guessing is a number?

I am using the latest version of Devexpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ASPxGridViewExporter.RenderBrickEvent](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewExportASPxGridViewExporter_RenderBricktopic) to format exported values.

```
<dx:ASPxGridViewExporter ID="gridExport" runat="server" GridViewID="grid" OnRenderBrick="grid_OnRenderBrickEvent"/>
```

```cs
protected void grid_OnRenderBrickEvent(object sender, ASPxGridViewExportRenderingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowType == GridViewRowType.Data && e.Column.FieldName == "yourcolumnfieldname")
    {
        string format = "0000000000.##";
        e.Text = ((decimal)e.Value).ToString(format);
        e.TextValue = ((decimal)e.Value).ToString(format);
}
```

Comment: There was no e.Column.FieldName property, so I used e.Column.Caption instead. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: You can cast e.Colum to GridViewDataColumn and use FieldName.